# Eclipse Java Luna SR2 - Unable to export project

Tags: java, eclipse, export

When selecting File > Export or right-click on Project > Export in Eclipse Java (using version Luna), I get a pop-up screen asking me to "Choose export destination", however there are no options. The only option is to click the "Cancel" button.

I am running Eclipse on Windows 8.1, 64-bit O/S. Have tried deleting and reinstalling Eclipse & searching for similar issues to this one but have not come up with anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will you post  screenshot of your error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a high enough "reputation". When I click "Export", I get a pop up screen reading:
"Choose export destination:"

"Select export destination:"

There are 4 buttons - "Back", "Next", "Finish", and "Cancel". All are greyed out except "Cancel".

Comment: Post pic somewhere else like fb, twitter and add link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/nNOca6j

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of Eclipse unable to detect the Android command is still working or something similar.

Go to Project--->Build Automatically and disable `Build Automatically` when you are exporting your apk file.

I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Hi @Anshul Tyagi

I tried disabling 'Build Automatically' - I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - Due to resolution error on Windows. Had to expand the Export Wizard pop-up box from the bottom right corner to see options.